# How to take and print the last word when reading a file?

Tags: c, string

In this code, I am trying to take the last word from a file but don't know how to do it? The result is like this. If I use **strrchr()** to take the last occurence then the last the occurence is newline and it won't return and any result. But I use **strchr** then the first occurence is also newline, so it won't take the last occurence. Instead the second last occurence will be taken but I want to print the last one.

**Data in file**

```
Name,ID,Phone number,Pin code,Deposit,Date
Ali Ahmed1,2222222222222,77777,6677,500,17-10-2020
Bilal Khan,2222222222222,77777,1122,500,18-10-2020
Ali Ahmed1,2222222222222,77777,6677,500,17-10-2020
Talha,2222222222222,77777,1122,500,19-10-2020
Ali Ahmed1,2222222222222,77777,1122,500,20-10-2020
Bilal Khan,2222222222222,77777,6677,500,17-10-2020
```

**Given result**

```
18-10-2020
19-10-2020
20-10-2020
```

**Expected result**

```
20-10-2020
```

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define STRING_LEN 200

int main(){
    FILE * fp1 = fopen("file.csv", "r");
    char string[STRING_LEN], pinFind[STRING_LEN];
    char * pinFound = NULL;
    char * word6;
    
    printf("Enter the pin: ");
    scanf("%s", pinFind);

    while(fgets(string, STRING_LEN, fp1)){
      pinFound = strstr(string, pinFind);
      if(pinFound){
        char * word1 = strtok(string, ",");
        char * word2 = strtok(NULL, ",");
        char * word3 = strtok(NULL, ",");
        char * word4 = strtok(NULL, ",");
        char * word5 = strtok(NULL, ",");
        char * word6 = strtok(NULL, ",");
      }
    }
    printf("%s", word6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "If I use strrchr()". Your code does not call `strrchr` nor `strchr`. What exactly is the problem with the code that you have shown?

Comment: @kaylum I called `strrchr` and `strchr` but it was not working what I want.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "last word in a file". Is the "Given result" what you want? That's showing three lines and not a word. If not that then what exactly is "last word in a file"? Show the code that doesn't work as that will make it clearer what you tried and may also help explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @kaylum I have update the code in which I added expected result.

Comment: Your description is misleading. That's certainly not the last word in the file. You really mean the last result in your match set. If that is the case you just need to remove the `printf` from the `while` loop and add the following after the loop `if (pinFound) printf("%s", word6);`

Comment: @kaylum Unfortunately ythat is not giving me any result.

Comment: You may have modified it incorrectly. Show the updated code. Or better still, think about it yourself. Do you understand what that change is doing? You can debug the code in a debugger to see why it doesn't work.

Comment: @kaylum you can now see the updated code

Comment: I said remove the `printf` from the `while` loop. But you have done more than that. you have also removed the `if` check. Please, you need to think about what you are doing and try to understand it. If you don't understand what the code does you should not use it and should not proceed until you do understand it.

Comment: Why use `strtok()`, you know the last value will be in the form of `17-10-2020` so just use `strrchr()` as you indicate to find the last `','` then read from one-past that to the end and use `sscanf()` to separate `day-mo-year` and create `yearmoday` with `sprintf()` and convert to `unsigned` with `strtoul()` or another call to `sscanf()` and keep the largest value found. (you can create a struct with string an unsigned values so when you need to output the result you can just output the string and not worry about a reverse conversion...)

Comment: @kaylum I updated the code, Is that what you want?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't know what are you saying?

Comment: I wrote up and answer for you further explaining the details.

Answer (score 0):

first it's a common CSV file so structure of file is so simple
second you want latest record not last word

for getting latest record i suggest use this guide line

start a linear search over dates and find latest date and save number of that line or you can save index of file pointer and now you have latest record

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comment above, you want to find the last (most recent) *Date* in the last field throughout the file. The last field is currently formatted with a date in the form of `day-mo-year`. So to find the last, you need to be able to determine what the maximum value for any of the date is. You can't do that in the format `day-mo-year` because `20-10-2020` is more recent than `31-12-2019`. So you need to swap the order around so you have `year` then `mo` then `date` because when you put that together (e.g. `20201020` can be compared to `20191231`) and will be larger.

So your challenge is how do I get `day-mo-year` and turn in into `yearmoday` and create an `unsigned` integer value for that which can be compared (you could do it with strings, but then you have to worry about LOCALE differences)

After you have found which is the most recent date, you apparently want to be able to output that in the original `day-mo-year` format -- so you better keep that stored somewhere or you will end up having to do the reverse conversion. The easiest way to do that will be to keep a struct that can coordinate the `unsigned` value with the original string, compare on the unsigned values, find the most recent date, and then you can output the original date format from the string member of the struct.

Let's start with a couple of constants for the max no. of chars in a line we will handle, and the no. or chars in the date string, along with a `struct` to coordinate both values:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXDT  16

typedef struct {        /* struct to coordinate original string with numeric value */
    char datestr[MAXDT];    /* typedef for convenience */
    unsigned dateval;
} datestrval;
...
```

(**note:** whenever you have to coordinate differing types of values as a single object, use a struct to hold all of them. You use a `typedef` for convenience so you can just use `datestrval name` to create an instance instead of having to write `struct datestrval name` -- it adds up when you have lots of parameters of that kind you pass to functions, etc....)

Now lets create a buffer to hold each line, the instance of the struct to hold the max values and open and validate the input file is open for reading:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char buf[MAXC];                         /* buffer to hold each line read */
    datestrval max = { .datestr = "" };     /* struct instance to hold max found */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    
    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
```

Now read each line from the file and obtain a pointer to the last `','` in the line using `strrchr()` and validate it is found, and if not, continue, reading the next line:

```
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {         /* read each line into buf */
        int mo, day, yr;                    /* vars for mo day and yr */
        char *p = strrchr (buf, ','),       /* pointer to last ',' in buf */
            tmpstr[MAXDT] = "";             /* temp string to use for rearranging */
        unsigned tmpu = 0;                  /* temp unsigned value for comparison */
        
        if (!p)                             /* if no last ',' get next line */
            continue;
```

Now starting one character after the last `','` separate into the `day`, `mo`, and `year` values. If the conversion fails, continue, and read the next line:

```
        /* starting 1 char after ',' split into day mo yr */
        if (sscanf (p + 1, "%u-%u-%4u", &day, &mo, &yr) != 3)
            continue;
```

Now create a temporary string from the values in the needed order (with leading zeros if necessary)

```
        /* put it together in tmpstr */
        sprintf (tmpstr, "%04u%02u%02u", yr, mo, day);
```

Convert the temporary string to an `unsigned` value, continue to next line on failure:

```
        if (sscanf (tmpstr, "%u", &tmpu) != 1)  /* convert tmpstr to unsigned in tmpu */
            continue;
```

Now compare the temporary value with what you currently have stored as the max date in your struct. If this is a more recent date, update the struct values to the current temporary string and unsigned values:

```
        if (tmpu > max.dateval) {           /* if tmpu greater than current max val */
            max.dateval = tmpu;             /* update struct with new max and string */
            strcpy (max.datestr, p + 1);
            max.datestr[strcspn (max.datestr, "\n")] = 0;   /* trim '\n' from string */
        }
    }
```

(**note:** `strname[strcspn (strname, "\n")] = 0;` is how you trim the `'\n'` from any string. `strcspn()` returns the number of characters (the length) not including the `'\n'`. So this provides a simple and safe method of overwriting the `'\n'` included in the buffer by `fgets()` with the *nul-terminating* character `'\0'` -- which is ASCII `0` so both are equivalent)

That's it, now the most recent date from the file along with its original format are stored in your `max` struct. Simply close the file and output your results:

```
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
    
    printf ("last date in file: %s\n", max.datestr);    /* output results */
}
```

(**note:** that is the complete program that can simply be pasted together)

**Example Use/Output**

With your example data in `dat/pinfile.txt` you would receive:

```
$ ./bin/lastdateinfile dat/pinfile.txt
last date in file: 20-10-2020
```

Give it a go, and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: how can I provide a file name here?

Comment: You provide it as the first argument to the program. When you run the program, it is `./program filename`. If you look where `fopen()` is, it is used as `fopen (argv[1], "r")`. That says use `argv[1]` (the first program argument) as the filename. If no argument is provided, then the program reads from `stdin` by default which allows you to pipe or redirect input to the program like a normal utility.

Comment: Bro, I spent my whole day understanding and doing but not getting results using your method.

Comment: Was your input file created on Windows? If so, you probably have UTF-16 character encoding. That requires wide-character types (thanks windows...) So make sure your data file is plain ASCII text without a BOM (Byte Order Mark). I have run this code on both Linux and Windows and it works fine either way -- so long as your input file is a proper ASCII file.

Comment: After the `if (sscanf (tmpstr, "%u", &tmpu) != 1)` check, add `printf ("\noriginal: %stmpstr: %s\nunsigned: %u\n", p + 1, tmpstr, tmpu);` to output the values created from each line. (a simple debugging check)

Comment: I am using Linux

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223372/discussion-between-david-c-rankin-and-quora-bai).